# $k \subseteq K$ be a field extension with $[K:k] = p$ prime, $f(X) \in k[x]$ with $\deg{f(X)} = p + 1$. $f$ has a root in $K$ iff has a root in $k$.

Tags: proof-verification, field-theory, extension-field

I just want to see if my proof is correct. 
It goes this way:

Suppose $\alpha \in K$ is a root of $f$, with minimal polynomial $p_\alpha \in k[X]$. Then $k \subseteq k(\alpha) \subseteq K$ is a composition of field extensions, with $[K: k] = [K: k(\alpha)][k(\alpha): k] = p$. This implies that either $[K:k(\alpha)] = p$ and $[k(\alpha): k] = 1$ or $[K: k(\alpha)] = 1$ and $[k(\alpha): k] = p$. As the first already establishes the desired result, we suppose that $[K: k(\alpha)] = 1$ and $[k(\alpha): k] = p$. Then, $p_\alpha | f$, i.e., $f = gp_\alpha$ for some $g \in k[X]$. Because $\deg{f} = p+1$ and $\deg{p_\alpha} = [k(\alpha) : k] = p$, we can conclude that $\deg{g} = 1$. Polynomials of degree 1 always have roots in their field of coefficients, which implies that $g$, and hence $f$, has a root in $k$.

Is this correct? Can you answer more elegantly?

Comment: It is absolutely correct and is the canonical way to do it. You can even exend the result to $deg(f)$ not divisible by $p$ with the same technique.

Comment: Well you don't need help here.